# DD command speed

Tags: windows, ssh, dd, darwin

So the situation is: I've got an old Ipod 3g that's been jailbroken, and it's connected to my server, a windows machine, via ssh. The reason for that is that I want to make a copy of /dev/rdisk0 Ipod partition to my server. I use DD command for that, but the problem is, that it runs incredibly slow. My Ipod is 32GB, and it takes almost 11 hours to get stuff done, considering that keeping connection alive and healthy for such a long time is problem itself(broken Pipe errors, connection timeouts etc).

So I was wondering, is there some kind of a way to make it at least a little bit faster, considering my overall setup? I was playing with bs for a little bit, but no success found there. The speed is somewhere around 1.9Mb/s, sometimes even slower.